# Setting Up Virtualenvwrapper in Scheduled Task

Tags: cron, virtualenvwrapper, pythonanywhere

I've a makefile target that depends on the environment having the VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT variable set. This works fine when I run it from a PythonAnywhere bash terminal. When I run the command from the scheduler the VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT variable is not set. To make the schedule work I manually set the variable in the schedule definition. See below. Is this the right way to make this work or am I missing something?

**This is What I Put in the Schedule Line**
`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh /bin/bash -c 'make yesterday_stats'`

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- that certainly should work.  I just set up a scheduled task for my own account with the command `FOO=23 /bin/bash -c 'echo $FOO' `, and got `23` in the log.  Maybe drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com with your username and we can help track this down?

Comment: Thanks Giles. Setting the env variable on the command line seems to work fine.